# How to check if ListTemplateType (enum) is list or library?

Tags: client-object-model, list-template

Is there some helper method for example in CSOM API to check if Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplateType is a list or a library, something like

```
IsLibrary(ListTemplateType type)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use [List.BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.basetype.aspx)? Something like:

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

bool isDocLib = list.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary;
```

Sorry if that's not valid C#, here's what I tested in JavaScript:

```
ctx=SP.ClientContext.get_current()
list=ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Pages")
ctx.load(list)
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        console.log(list.get_baseType() === SP.BaseType.documentLibrary)
    },
    function() {
        console.log(arguments)
    }
)
```

Comment: this seems to be it - an easy way to check if a list is a library of any type (document, picture etc)

Comment: In SPO, and possibly 2013 On-Prem onwards, you should also check for ListTemplateType.MySiteDocumentLibrary // MySiteDocumentLibrary.Value = 700

Answer (score 2):

To determine [ListTemplateType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype) the following method could be used:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get List Template Type
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list">List client object</param>
/// <returns>returns List template type </returns>
private static ListTemplateType GetListTemplateType(List list)
{
      try
      {
          return (ListTemplateType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ListTemplateType), list.BaseTemplate.ToString());
      }
      catch
      {
          throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("ListTemplateType", list.BaseTemplate, typeof(ListTemplateType));
      }
}
```

[List.BaseTemplate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.basetemplate.aspx)  is used for resolving [ListTemplateType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listtemplatetype)

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{

     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     ctx.Load(list, l => l.BaseTemplate);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     var listType = GetListTemplateType(list);
     if (listType == ListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary)
     {
         //...
     }

}
```

Comment: In SPO, and possibly 2013 On-Prem onwards, you should also check for ListTemplateType.MySiteDocumentLibrary // MySiteDocumentLibrary.Value = 700